# After Session TImeout url goes to developer login instead of App login page Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am facing issue in Session Timeout URL. As it takes end user to Developer Login page instead of App Login page. For Session Timeout URL i am using Substitution string of #LOGOUT_URL# (as shown in image) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m2wi.png).
Also for Home URL i am using application item as show in image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL5Tl.png).
How can i fix this issue?

Oracle Apex Version 20.2

Thanks

After session timeout when user click "Sign in again" it should take user to App login page.

Comment: Did you try to put `&APP_LOGO_URL.` into "Session timeout URL" property?

Comment: Yes, first i tried this but only some substitution strings are supported as mentioned in item help.

Only three substitution items are supported in this URL:
&APP_SESSION.
&SESSION.
&APP_ID.

Comment: Does it go to developer login if you're not logged in as developer ? launch app in an incognito window and let it time out

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I have checked in incognito mode.